# What's the best way of storing and extracting files inside the .jar archive?

Tags: java, jar, archive

I am looking for a way to store files inside the jar (and extract them), but it must work when running/debugging from Eclipse as well.

**explanation:**
Storing files as in images that I want to use for an icon of a Frame. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Are you asking a question or making a complaint?

Comment: Nope, asking a question :P That's what stackOverflow is for, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think that the question is a bit unclear.

What is it that you want to do? You can create and read from jar-files using JarInputStream/JarOutputStream, and you can also read files from jar-files that are on the classpath using Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)

Comment: Hey, that last line is what I was looking for :D

Now does that only work when everything's all packed inside a .jar ?

Or will it work when running from Eclipse as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don not get your question clearly.
Eclipse can export runnable jar files , right click on the project name and choose export. Then from the dialog choose runnable jar file under java category.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that, I've edited my main question so it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Creating JAR file using Eclipse IDE is pretty much easy.

Follow the simple steps.
1. Right click on your project, which you want to create a JAR file.
2. Select Export from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse understands Ant build files.  Write a build file that (compiles &) Jar's the code at the same time and this becomes a non-issue.